# How to group similar records by single value

Tags: mysql, group-by, grouping

I have an issue where i wrote a script that finds students that are in more then one school, and im getting duplicate records for each class under that school.

The problem is that the students share the same unique primary key, so i can't group by that. And i can't group by school or class as that would eliminate other students.

Basically i want to group all records for each student according to school, so that there is only 1 record per school for each student.

I don't really care what class shows for the grouping, as i really want to find students that are listed in more then one school.

For example

```
id    first    Last    Class School
22     mike     bundy    1     tan
22     mike     bundy    2     tan
22     mike     bundy    3     light
```

I want to group it down to this

```
id    first    Last    Class School
22     mike     bundy    1     tan
22     mike     bundy    3     light
```

Comment: Does that mean you don't care about the Class field at all or that you want the lowest class value? Can you be a little more concise?

Comment: did you consider using distinct ?

Comment: I don't care about the class field at all- but its required in the join to find what school the student is associated with.

Comment: I can't seem to get distinct to work on and individual student row.. This db has too many records to do a simple distinct, as that would omit other students.

Comment: The columns in your select list do not match the data that you are showing your data result.  What column in the select relates to each data column?

Comment: I've cleaned up up the query so it makes more sense on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use the group by clause to get single record for each school. Like

```
SELECT
        user.user_id,
        user.last_name,
        user.first_name,
        student.sis_id,
        organization.`NAME`AS school,
        count(*) as Count
    FROM
        user
    JOIN student ON user.user_id = student.user_id
    JOIN x_user_group ON _user.user_id = x_user_group.user_id
    JOIN group ON _x_user_group.group_id = group.group_id
    JOIN organization ON group.owner_id = organization.organization_id
Group by
        user.user_id,
        user.last_name,
        user.first_name,
        student.sis_id,
        school
Order by
        user.last_name,
        user.first_name
```

The aggregate function count is requried as group by is used. Just ignore it in result set. Now you will have one student in each school.

Comment: That works! Thanks.. So i guess the group by has to go down to the school level